# How to formulate the NOR operator in Java

Tags: java

I was just wondering how can get the NOR operator in Java like this

```
if (!(foo == "bar" || foo1=="bar1")){
...
}
```

Edit : I was looking for a more efficient way to write that

Comment: I suspect your problem is actually with string equality comparisons...

Comment: In response to your edit... a more *efficient* way? How would you expect anything to be more efficient? Is this somehow a bottleneck for you?

Comment: I thought there may be a more direct expression to simplify reading

Comment: The only other way to write that statement, is to use the equivalent "and" statement by bringing the negation through the equation to get !foo.equals("bar") && !foo1.equals("bar1") (as stated in aioobe's answer.) But you would have to implement the logic in a circuit to notice any difference.

Comment: Note that Java is a word and not an acronym

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> [...] ***I was looking for a more efficient way to write that***

There is no NOR operator in Java. You have to do it as you've done

```
!(A || B)
```

or, `!A && !B` of course.

Comment: Only one change is use equals() because of String comparison.

Comment: Well, it *may* be correct to use `==` of course. Those cases are rare of course, but still.

Comment: "may be", but equals() make sure, isn't?

Comment: @thinksteep `equals` also makes sure you get an NPE if the left operand is `null`. Of course, in 99.9% of cases using `==` is just a sign of programmer error.